# how to drop an element into a div and retrieve the coordinates relative to the div element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

i have a div element with id="drag", if a div element with id='drag' is dragged and dropped onto a div element with id="drop", it will display the coordinates value relative to the div element with id="drop" . I've managed to retrieve the coordinates relative to the div id="drop", but when the page is scrolled, the Y value also changes. how to solve this so that when the page is scrolled the Y value remains relative to the div with id='drop'? here is my code below

`

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>jQuery UI Droppable</title>
  </head>
  <body style="height: 200vh">
    <div
      id="drop"
      style="
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: brown;
        margin: 0 auto;
      "
    ></div>
    <div
      id="drag"
      style="background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px"
    ></div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#drag").draggable();
      $("#drop").droppable({
        accept: "#drag",
        drop: function (e) {
          var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
          const coordinates = [
            Math.round(e.pageX - rect.left),
            Math.round(e.pageY - rect.top),
          ];
          console.log(coordinates[0]);
          console.log(coordinates[1]);
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

At least from here, it never changes.

you can check it like that:

```
$(function () {

var coordinates;

  $("#drag").draggable();
  $("#drop").droppable({
    accept: "#drag",
    drop: function (e) {
    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    coordinates = [
        Math.round(e.pageX - rect.left),
        Math.round(e.pageY - rect.top),
      ];
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(coordinates[0]);
        console.log(coordinates[1]);
      }, 500);

    },
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the result is the same. what I want is when the page is not scrolling and I place the div element with id = "drag" in the lower right corner of the div element with id = "drop", coordinate[1] = it gets the value 590, but when I scroll the page down a bit and placing the div element with id = "drag" is the same as before, the coordinate[1] value will change. How to handle that problem?

Comment: I've tried it, but the result is the same. what I want is when the page is not scrolling and I place the div element with id = "drag" in the lower right corner of the div element with id = "drop", coordinate[1] = it gets the value 590, but when I scroll the page down a bit and placing the div element with id = "drag" is the same as before, the coordinate[1] value will change. How to handle that problem?